# simple string question - the Single quotation marks and Double quotation marks inside the string just make the string into several parts

Tags: python

I need to use a long string for testing regular expression. However, the test string is always altered by the inside quotation marks, which leads to the whole string seperetaed into several parts and some of them are not included into the string, and thus error occurred.

```
    str1=r"row Id="7" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="4" \n
         CreationDate="2008-07-31T22:17:57.883"\n
         Score="49" ViewCount="0" Body="<p>An explicit cast to double i"
```

Would you pleae tell me how to tackle this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: As an aside: Using regular expressions to parse HTML is not a good idea, especially in Python which doesn't support recursive regexes, and where there's [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a multiline string:

```
str1 = r"""row Id="7" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="4"
           CreationDate="2008-07-31T22:17:57.883"
           Score="49" ViewCount="0" Body="<p>An explicit cast to double i"""
```

As long as your string doesn't span multiple lines, you can also use an alternative quote character:

```
str1 = r'row Id="7" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="4"'
```

or (if you have both kinds of quotes inside your string) escape the quotes (but, as Ned Batchelder noted, then you can't use a raw string anymore):

```
str1 = 'row Id="7" PostTypeId=\'2\' ParentId="4"'
```

Comment: One note: your last example won't work, because it's a raw string (r prefix), so the backslashes escape the apostrophes, but they are also included literally in the string.